# OpenGL application causing Stack Overflow in d3d11.dll

Tags: c++, windows, opengl, dll, stack-overflow

This problem only started happening after updating Windows 10 to version 1703, the program works fine on version 1607.

Upon creating an OpenGL 4.6 context, a stack overflow exception is triggered in d3d11.dll when invoking SwapBuffers(). Below is a summary of the contents of the stack (read from the bottom up). Why is my purely OpenGL program invoking functions in d3d11.dll? I don't know how to even go about debugging this, any tips would be appreciated.

System specs: GeForce GT 745A with driver version 388.13, Windows 10 version 1703, i7 4790S, 8GB ram

EDIT: Loaded symbols, got a much more helpful call stack:

```
d3d11.dll!NDXGI::CDevice::SubmitCommandCB(void *,struct _D3DDDICB_SUBMITCOMMAND const *)    Unknown
-- This block repeats several times...
nvwgf2umx.dll!00007ffdd4a226d5()    Unknown
nvwgf2umx.dll!00007ffdd4a18830()    Unknown
nvwgf2umx.dll!00007ffdd4a2363d()    Unknown
nvwgf2umx.dll!00007ffdd4d60d27()    Unknown
nvwgf2umx.dll!00007ffdd4a226d5()    Unknown
-------------------------------------------
nvwgf2umx.dll!00007ffdd4a18830()    Unknown
nvwgf2umx.dll!00007ffdd4a2363d()    Unknown
nvwgf2umx.dll!00007ffdd4d60d27()    Unknown
nvwgf2umx.dll!00007ffdd4194afb()    Unknown
nvwgf2umx.dll!00007ffdd418e57e()    Unknown
nvwgf2umx.dll!00007ffdd41b3f1d()    Unknown
nvwgf2umx.dll!00007ffdd4183518()    Unknown
nvwgf2umx.dll!00007ffdd4183750()    Unknown
d3d11.dll!NDXGI::CDevice::CreateDriverInstance(void *,void *,void *,void *,bool,bool,enum D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL,unsigned int,long (**)(struct D3D10DDI_HDEVICE,unsigned int,unsigned __int64,void *,unsigned __int64,void *))   Unknown
d3d11.dll!CDevice::CreateDriverInstance(class CContext *,void *,void *,void *,void *,unsigned int,long (**)(struct D3D10DDI_HDEVICE,unsigned int,unsigned __int64,void *,unsigned __int64,void *))  Unknown
d3d11.dll!CContext::LUCCompleteLayerConstruction(void)  Unknown
d3d11.dll!NOutermost::CDeviceChild::LUCCompleteLayerConstruction(void)  Unknown
d3d11.dll!NOutermost::CDevice::CreateLayeredChild(unsigned int,void const *,unsigned __int64,struct ID3D11LayeredUseCounted *,struct _GUID const &,void * *)    Unknown
d3d11.dll!CDevice::LLOCompleteLayerConstruction(void)   Unknown
d3d11.dll!NDXGI::CDevice::LLOCompleteLayerConstruction(void)    Unknown
d3d11.dll!NOutermost::CDevice::FinalConstruct(struct NOutermost::CDevice::TConstructorArgs const &) Unknown
d3d11.dll!TComObject<class NOutermost::CDevice>::TComObject<class NOutermost::CDevice>(void *,struct NOutermost::CDevice::TConstructorArgs const &,struct _GUID const &,void * *)   Unknown
d3d11.dll!TComObject<class NOutermost::CDevice>::CreateInstance(struct NOutermost::CDevice::TConstructorArgs const &,void *,void *,struct _GUID const &,void * *)   Unknown
d3d11.dll!D3D11CreateLayeredDevice(unsigned int,void const *,unsigned __int64,struct ID3D11LayeredDevice *,struct _GUID const &,void * *)   Unknown
d3d11.dll!D3D11CoreCreateLayeredDevice()    Unknown
d3d11.dll!D3D11RegisterLayersAndCreateDevice(struct D3D11_EXTENSIONS const &,class NDXGI::CUMDAdapter *,enum D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL,enum D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL,unsigned __int64,unsigned int,struct ID3D11Device * *)    Unknown
d3d11.dll!D3D11CoreCreateDevice()   Unknown
d3d11.dll!D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChainImpl(struct IDXGIAdapter *,enum D3D_DRIVER_TYPE,struct HINSTANCE__ *,unsigned int,enum D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL const *,unsigned int,unsigned int,struct DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC const *,struct IDXGISwapChain * *,struct ID3D11Device * *,enum D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL *,struct ID3D11DeviceContext * *)    Unknown
d3d11.dll!D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain()   Unknown
d3d11.dll!D3D11CreateDeviceImpl(struct IDXGIAdapter *,enum D3D_DRIVER_TYPE,struct HINSTANCE__ *,unsigned int,enum D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL const *,unsigned int,unsigned int,struct ID3D11Device * *,enum D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL *,struct ID3D11DeviceContext * *)  Unknown
d3d11.dll!D3D11CreateDevice()   Unknown
nvoglv64.dll!0000000058f193a9() Unknown
nvoglv64.dll!0000000058f18438() Unknown
nvoglv64.dll!0000000058f40b8e() Unknown
nvoglv64.dll!0000000058f3fcd3() Unknown
nvoglv64.dll!0000000058f22607() Unknown
nvoglv64.dll!0000000058f41a42() Unknown
nvoglv64.dll!00000000590291fd() Unknown
nvoglv64.dll!000000005903437d() Unknown
nvoglv64.dll!00000000590452e7() Unknown
nvoglv64.dll!0000000058ee8ffe() Unknown
nvoglv64.dll!00000000590095e2() Unknown
nvoglv64.dll!0000000058febb4d() Unknown
nvoglv64.dll!0000000058febc60() Unknown
nvoglv64.dll!0000000058ef9e66() Unknown
nvoglv64.dll!0000000058ef9fd5() Unknown
nvoglv64.dll!0000000058ef9dc4() Unknown
nvoglv64.dll!0000000058ef98c6() Unknown
nvoglv64.dll!0000000058ee355a() Unknown
opengl32.dll!wglSwapBuffers()   Unknown
gdi32full.dll!SwapBuffers() Unknown
```

Answer (score 3):

Until thorough examination of the code and associated input data, we can only speculate on possible reasons.

Looking at repeated blocks in the call chain, you may have hit the stack with an infinite recursion somewhere in the driver. This may be due to erroneous parameter passed to an OpenGL API call or due to a bug in the OpenGL implementation. Before blaming Nvidia or Microsoft you should thoroughly check your program. In order to debug this error you may try the following:

- Before anything else, implement proper OpenGL error checking. 
  Make sure that you retrieve return codes from all OpenGL calls, check them for failure, print a debugging message and trigger a breakpoint or terminate the program if any of these calls fail (see e.g. [here](https://blog.nobel-joergensen.com/2013/01/29/debugging-opengl-using-glgeterror/)). Implement debug callback extension in debug mode, like [here](https://blog.nobel-joergensen.com/2013/02/17/debugging-opengl-part-2-using-gldebugmessagecallback/).
- Run program under conventional C++ debugger, like the one in Visual Studio. Inspect stack, and heap for possible corruption. Enable more compiler warnings, try various static code checkers and runtime analyzers if they can find anything suspicious.
- Run program under graphics debugger, such as [Nvidia Nsight](https://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-nsight-visual-studio-edition) and look for possible errors in API calls, on various stages of the pipeline and in shaders
- Find and isolate OpenGL function call that leads to the error. Gradually delete or comment out the pieces of the code that look the most suspicious (e.g. the code closer to the crash, code that uses heap memory etc.). See if error disappears. If it does, than you may have removed the code that causes the error. Bring it back and see if error appears again. Start with large blocks of code and gradually reduce the amount of code you remove to make the search more precise. The end goal is to come up with a [minimal code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reproduces the error.
- When you found it, post this minimal code on StackOverflow (e.g. add to your question as an update), so that community could check it out.
- If there are no errors in your minimal example, but it crashes, submit bug report, including the minimal example code, to Nvidia. Meanwhile you may also try different driver versions to see whether they are affected.
- You may also try to run the code on Intel or AMD graphics. For example, you have Intel graphics integrated into your CPU. If the problem is also observable on another GPU, then it is likely not Nvidia's fault (it is very unlikely that two different vendors made the same error in the same place)
- If your code is portable across OS, or at least if the minimal example is, try to build and run it on another OS. Linux have excellent tools to debug C++ code. Sometimes simply changing the compiler reveals a lot of obvious bugs. Plus, you will have valgrind, clang sanitizers and different implementations of OpenGL stack, including graphics drivers (e.g. there are two different implementations of Nvidia driver, a proprietary from Nvidia and open-source Nouveau driver). There are also OpenGL-related debugging tools on Linux.
- Note, that when dissecting your code trying to isolate the erroneous call, you may not find one, because in some situations there are several calls necessary to cause the issue. These calls may be adjacent to each other, or they may be spread across multiple rendering frames. Things are getting particularly difficult when using multithreading and/or multiple contexts. In these cases, minimizing the amount of code, removing threading and context should help.
- Note, that the fact that the error does not appear on your previous configuration (e.g. different Windows version), or on other vendor's implementation of OpenGL, does not necessarily mean there is no bug. It may be been hidden or ignored by the different implementation. Some bugs may not manifest until very specific conditions are met. The more configurations you try (operating system, compiler, OpenGL implementation, driver) the more bugs you are able to expose. Hopefully, the tips above will help you to find those bugs and conditions.

Happy debugging!